# Python Selenium stuck at webdriver.Ie()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am running Selenium in python with internet explorer using `IEDriverServer_Win32_3.150.2`
from [selenium.dev site](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Setting up the driver
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
caps['nativeEvents'] = True
caps['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
caps['InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
caps['requireWindowsFocus'] = True

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\IEDriverServer.exe", capabilities=caps)
```

The driver successfully open IE 11 with no warning and with the welcoming page `"This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."` however Python seems to stuck at executing `drive = webdriver.Ie()` and I have no way to call `driver.get()`

I have followed the instruction by making sure all protected mode turns on.

Comment: Do you have any errors come up?

Comment: Nope,  not at all...

Comment: I am EXACTLY the same as Computer 2 in this problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747790/python-action-stucked-when-launching-selenium-ie11-webdriver-or-when-executing-j    i am now trying to install other windows 7 to see if the window update did something to IE after it end support for IE11 in june 2021

Answer (score 1):

I used VirtualBox to install Window 7 and without updates solved the problem. Thanks all

One thing I notice why IE11 not working in the host computer is under "About Internet Explorer" it doesn't shows the IE version but instead the Window 10 version.

[image]

In the working VM, the IE displays the actual version of IE:

[image]

I believe this is why it is stuck in the webdriver, something to do with the IE itself.